# Can I have an SVG's CSS Stroke property inherit a color from the SVG markup?

Tags: css, svg

**Edit**: In my case, I need IE11 support, so CSS variables aren't the way to go. If you [can use CSS variables](https://caniuse.com/css-variables), see Kaiido's answer. If not, see Paul's answer.

---

I've got a simple website with the concept of "light" and "dark" themes. Light themes are white or very light backgrounds, and dark themes are some darker color. Most components on the website work by adjusting their color based on their position inside elements that have these themes. For example:

```css
.dark-theme {
  background-color: black;
}

.light-theme  {
  background-color: white;
}

/* When the paragraph is inside a dark theme */
.dark-theme p,
.light-theme .dark-theme p {
  color: white;
}

/* When the paragraph is inside a light theme */
.light-theme p,
.dark-theme .light-theme p {
   color: black;
}

.dark-theme, .light-theme {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-theme">
  <p>Light Theme</p>
  <div class="dark-theme">
    <p>Dark Theme</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dark-theme">
  <p>Dark Theme</p>
  <div class="light-theme">
    <p>Light Theme</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This allows us to have each component just define how it needs to display in dark vs. light theme, and its placement in the DOM will take care of the rest.

The catch here is that we must actually write definitions for each case (dark on light, and light on dark). If we don't define one case, then we will get incorrect behaviour when the elements are nested.

However, I cannot get this to work with SVGs in a specific scenario where the SVG has a `stroke` defined as an HTML attribute. We are using icons that come from somewhere else so adjusting the SVG markup is not an option.

What we want is: when an SVG is on a light background (`.light-theme`), the SVG should be whatever color is in the SVG markup (there may be more than one). Whenever an SVG is on a dark background (`.dark-theme`), we want it to be white (working).

Below is what happens when we try the same thing as we did above with the `<p>` using the `stroke` or `fill` properties of the SVG. It seems I cannot use `unset`, `inherit`, or `initial` to get it to fall back to the SVG's actual value. Is this expected?

And if I just don't define the behaviour for the light theme, it will fail in cases where the themes are nested.

**So, the tl;dr is: how can I override `stroke` and `fill` properties that were set using CSS with a more specific CSS rule to get an SVG to use its original color that was defined in its markup?**

```css
/* When the paragraph is inside a dark theme */
.dark-theme p,
.light-theme .dark-theme p {
  color: white;
}

/* When the paragraph is inside a light theme */
.light-theme p,
.dark-theme .light-theme p {
   color: black;
}

/* When the circle is inside a dark theme */
.dark-theme svg circle,
.light-theme .dark-theme svg circle {
  stroke: white;
  fill: white;
}

/* When the circle is inside a light theme */
.light-theme svg circle,
.dark-theme .light-theme svg circle {
   stroke: initial; /* How to make the circle red here? */
   fill: initial; /* How to make the circle red here? */
}

/** helpers below here **/

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.light-theme, .dark-theme {
  padding: 10px;
}

.dark-theme {
  background-color: black;
}

.light-theme  {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-theme">
  <p>Light Theme</p>
  <div class="dark-theme">
    <p>Dark Theme</p>
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    </svg> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dark-theme">
  <p>Dark Theme</p>
  <div class="light-theme">
    <p>Light Theme</p>
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    </svg> 
  </div>
</div>
```

By request: here's an example of how it could be nested. There are essentially no DOM constraints we can rely on.

```html
<div class="light-theme"> <!-- nesting can go light > dark > light > dark, etc -->
  <div class="dark-theme">
    <p>Dark Theme</p>
    <div class="something anything really"> <!-- this may or may not be here -->
      <div class="another container dark-theme"> <!-- this may or may not be here -->
        <div class="light-theme">
          <p>Light Theme</p>
          <svg height="100" width="100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
          </svg> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How many nest level can there be? Is a dark > light > dark situation possible? Otherwise, `.dark-theme svg:not(.light-theme *) circle, .light-theme .dark-theme svg circle` would do what you want, in case you can only have either dark or light alone and dark > light or light > dark. But this will fails in case of deeper nesting.

Comment: dark > light > dark and light > dark > light are possible.

Comment: you do deal with your votes as you wish, but I'm a bit surprised by the fact you acccepted Paul's answer, which is still requiring a fixed DOM structure, and which is still using your rule that does fail after 3 nesting levels. Could you please clarify if your use case has changed for these issues to not be issues anymore?

Comment: @Kaiido the advantage of Paul's answer is that I can use SASS to write a few lines that can generate a selector that will support n levels of nesting. We need IE11 support so CSS variables aren't a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only apply the dark theme colours to the SVG when it is a direct child of the `div.dark-theme`.

```
.dark-theme > svg circle {
  stroke: white;
  fill: white;
}
```

`a > b` means apply this rule if `b` is one of the children of `a`.

If you potentially have deeper nesting, you could expand this rule like follows:

```
.dark-theme > svg circle,
.dark-theme > :not(.light-theme) > svg circle,
.dark-theme > :not(.light-theme) > :not(.light-theme) > svg circle,
.dark-theme > :not(.light-theme) > :not(.light-theme) > :not(.light-theme) > svg circle,
.dark-theme > :not(.light-theme) > :not(.light-theme) > :not(.light-theme) > :not(.light-theme) > svg circle
{
  stroke: white;
  fill: white;
}
```

It's perhaps a bit ugly, but it works and is simple. :)

Demo:

```css
/* When the paragraph is inside a dark theme */
.dark-theme p,
.light-theme .dark-theme p {
  color: white;
}

/* When the paragraph is inside a light theme */
.light-theme p,
.dark-theme .light-theme p {
   color: black;
}

/* When the circle is inside a dark theme */
.dark-theme > svg circle,
.dark-theme > :not(.light-theme) > svg circle,
.dark-theme > :not(.light-theme) > :not(.light-theme) > svg circle,
.dark-theme > :not(.light-theme) > :not(.light-theme) > :not(.light-theme) > svg circle,
.dark-theme > :not(.light-theme) > :not(.light-theme) > :not(.light-theme) > :not(.light-theme) > svg circle
{
  stroke: white;
  fill: white;
}

/** helpers below here **/

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.light-theme, .dark-theme {
  padding: 10px;
}

.dark-theme {
  background-color: black;
}

.light-theme  {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-theme">
  <p>Light Theme</p>
  <div class="dark-theme">
    <p>Dark Theme</p>
    <div class="foo">
      <svg height="100" width="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dark-theme">
  <p>Dark Theme</p>
  <div class="light-theme">
    <p>Light Theme</p>
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    </svg> 
  </div>
</div>

<!-- UPDATE -->
<div class="light-theme"> <!-- nesting can go light > dark > light > dark, etc -->
  <div class="dark-theme">
    <p>Dark Theme</p>
    <div class="something anything really"> <!-- this may or may not be here -->
      <div class="another container dark-theme"> <!-- this may or may not be here -->
        <div class="light-theme">
          <p>Light Theme</p>
          <svg height="100" width="100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
          </svg> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the DOM is more complex than that as it's rendered by a CMS. Components can be nested in more complicated ways and so won't have a reliable relationship to write such a selector for. This is why we generally need to define `.dark-theme` and `.light-theme .dark-theme` for example.

Comment: Can you give an example of a more complex one?

Comment: Added - there's essentially no constraints in the DOM that we can rely on. Really the question boils down to less about the selector and more about why stroke and fill can't be set to inherit values from SVG attributes.

Comment: @JamieCounsell because those particular SVG attributes are simply mapped CSS properties.

Comment: @JamieCounsell My solution still works fine with your new snippet.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau but it wouldn't work if they wrapped the svg in any other container than .*-theme. For instance `<div class="dark-theme"><div class="foo"><svg...`. They stated that "there's essentially no constraints in the DOM that we can rely on", having the svg as a direct child of the theme wrapper is a big constraint.

Comment: @Kaiido True. But I asked OP to supply an example of a "more complicated DOM" that they claimed wouldn't work.

Comment: Well I gave you one didn't I?

Comment: Ok. I can just brute force it. :)

Comment: This works great and supports IE11. I was able to write a SASS for loop to generate this too!

Answer (score 2):

The `stroke` and `fill` attributes map directly to CSS properties, with less specificity than any *true* (not inherited) CSS property.

We should be able to do what you want easily through the [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr()) CSS function, which would allow us to duplicate that rule with an higher specificity, but it's still not yet supported anywhere.

One possible workaround, since you are willing to recolorize your SVGs entirely to white, is to use filters to do so, instead of changing the `fill` and `stroke`. This way, we can force a `filter:none` when we are in light-mode.

Note that your current rule actually fails, even for the text's `color`, in cases like *.dark-theme > .light-theme > .dark-theme* since both rules have the same specificity. To fix this, we have to rely on inheritance instead, and for `filter` that means using CSS-variables.

```css
.dark-theme {
  color: white;
  --filter: brightness(0) grayscale(1) invert(1);
}
.light-theme {
   color: black;
   --filter: none;
}
svg circle {
  filter: var(--filter);
}
```

```css
.dark-theme {
  color: white;
  --filter: brightness(0) grayscale(1) invert(1);
}
.light-theme {
   color: black;
   --filter: none;
}
svg circle {
  filter: var(--filter);
}

/** helpers below here **/

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.light-theme, .dark-theme {
  padding: 10px;
}

.dark-theme {
  background-color: black;
}

.light-theme  {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-theme">
  <p>Light Theme</p>
  <div class="dark-theme">
    <p>Dark Theme</p>
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    </svg> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dark-theme">
  <p>Dark Theme</p>
  <div class="light-theme">
    <p>Light Theme</p>
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    </svg> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="light-theme"> <!-- nesting can go light > dark > light > dark, etc -->
  <p>Light Theme</p>
  <div class="dark-theme">
    <p>Dark Theme</p>
    <div class="something anything really"> <!-- this may or may not be here -->
      <div class="another container dark-theme"> <!-- this may or may not be here -->
        <div class="light-theme">
          <p>Light Theme</p>
          <svg height="100" width="100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
          </svg> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="light-theme"> <!-- nesting can go light > dark > light > dark, etc -->
  <p>Light Theme</p>
  <div class="dark-theme">
    <p>Dark Theme</p>
    <div class="something anything really"> <!-- this may or may not be here -->
      <div class="another container dark-theme"> <!-- this may or may not be here -->
        <div class="light-theme">
          <p>Light Theme</p>
          <div class="dark-theme">
            <p>Dark Theme</p>
            <svg height="100" width="100">
              <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
            </svg> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```